# Exponential sum divided by exponential sum

Tags: exponential-function, fractions

Quite simply, $$\frac{e^{x}-1}{e^{x/2}-1}=e^{x/2}+1$$
I have no idea what combination of exponential properties or fraction identity tricks would result in the RHS of the equation. I apologize if it's super obvious and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: $(e^{x/2})^2=e^x$.

Comment: I'm also realizing as I reread the title that it's completely misleading. Once again, my apologies. And to clarify: I would like to see the simplification process to get from the LHS to the RHS of the equation.

Comment: Factor the numerator as $\left(e^{x/2}-1\right)\left(e^{x/2}+1\right)$

Comment: You are given $( y^2-1)/(y-1)= (y+1)$

Answer (score 2):

If $u=e^{x/2}$ then the top is $u^2-1$ and bottom is $u-1.$ Now use $u^2-1=(u-1)(u+1).$